# AppleScript - Expected end of line but found identifier when opening email program

Tags: email, applescript

I'm working on building a small plugin in AppleScript that will find the default mail app and open that up and paste in a subject and body.

I get the error "Expected end of line but found identifier."

```
on run
    set mailClient to getDefaultMailClient() -- store application id
    tell application id mailClient
        set msg to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"subject here", visible:true}
        tell msg to make new to recipient with properties {address:"email.com"}
    end tell
end run

on getDefaultMailClient()
    set prefPath to (path to preferences as text) & "com.apple.LaunchServices.plist"
    tell application "System Events"
        try
            value of property list item "LSHandlerRoleAll" of ¬
                (first property list item of property list item "LSHandlers" of ¬
                    property list file prefPath whose value of property list items ¬
                    contains "mailto")
        on error
            "com.apple.mail"
        end try
    end tell
end getDefaultMailClient
```

This works fine when it opens up the program Mail on my computer but I want it to work for Entourage and any other email program for OSX.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than anticipate various clients and create specific code for them, you can take advantage of the abstraction the `mailto:` URL scheme provides - it will open a new email form in the default email client:

```applescript
on newEmailForm(addr, subj, body)
  do shell script "open " & ¬
    quoted form of ("mailto:" & addr & "?subject=" & subj & "&body=" & body)
end newEmailForm

# Sample invocation:
my newEmailForm("somebody@some.net", "This is my subject line", "")
```

Note that the above uses `do shell script` with `open` rather than `open location` - the former conveniently automatically encodes the strings for inclusion in a URI, whereas the latter requires you to pass an already-encoded string.

Comment: Although it may not be applicable to jarrod, I don't think you can specify which account you are sending from with mailto links. Can you?

Comment: @adayzdone: You're right: you cannot - apparently the URL scheme itself doesn't allow it: 

"Originator fields like From [...] when present in the URI, MUST be ignored." - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6068.txt. The next best thing (probably inadequate) is to use `reply-to=`, though that's also not part of the scheme per se, though clients in practice seem to support it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing commands for each client.

```
if mailClient = "com.apple.mail" then
    tell application "Mail"
        --insert your code
    end tell
else if mailClient = "com.something.else" then
    tell application "something.else"
        --insert your code
    end tell
end if
```